# Stack Overflow ask question page not completely shown

Tags: bug

I need to ask a question on Stack Overflow about a C# error, but the question page is incomplete and the menubar for the question textbox and the question preview are not shown, like my screenshot below.

[image]

Now what do I need to do?

Comment: Did you [clear your browser's cache](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: Looks like some CSS or images are being blocked. What does the network tab of the browser developer tools tell you when you refresh the page? Anything not loading?

Comment: Refresh your browser cache, and check your network connection?

Comment: No its not working same problem occurs.

Comment: My inbox , achievement button also not work.

Comment: Stackoverflow Meta works perfect . Why stackoverflow not works.

Comment: Looks like JavaScript problems then - it works here on Meta as the files are served from a different location. As others have said - clear your cache, do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5). If still not working - check the console for JavaScript errors, see if there are any blocked files in the network tab.

Comment: @Anu Try using Incognito Mode (Chrome) or Private Browsing Mode (Firefox) or using InPrivate Mode (IE) or better, check with another browser, or in another device. Finally try it with another device on another network, preferably with non-proxy direct Internet connected, unrestricted device.

Comment: @Oded ^ Will that help?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - it could narrow down the cause.

Comment: Are there errors in your console (f12)?